# Sending 64 bit numbers to and from php/MySQL server with JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, 64-bit

I am working on an app that will have to send 64bit numbers back and forth with a php api via JSON which will store and retrieve them from a MySQL database. How do you format them in JSON so as not to lose any precision? Should I send them as raw integers? Strings? Hex? I'm not sure what the best way is to handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`

```
$yourresultsarray = json_decode($json, true, 64, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
```

or you could simply set the `precision` parameter on PHP.ini.

```
<?php
ini_set('precision',20); //<--- Add this on top as shown
```

Comment: Ok. So when I serialize this information to JSON from an NSDictionary on the iOS side, it should be able to handle the long long integers okay?

Comment: When you are serializing it ,the whole data will be encoded in a string format ..so you don't need to about that. Yeah this will suffice, also you can very well use the alternate solution I suggested using the `precision` parameter.